# Inject value from middleware into Razor Page HTML body

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, razor-pages

I have a middleware which calculates Razor Page execution time:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await next.Invoke();
    sw.Stop();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<div class=\"container\">Processing time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms<div>");
});
```

It works fine, however HTML created by `WriteAsync` is added at the very end of the response, after closing `</html>` tag.

How can I place - pass or inject - a value of `sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` calculated by the middleware in specific place inside HTML body? Using ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the HTML Agility Pack.

You can use the `LoadHtml` and `HtmlNode.CreateNode` methods to create the html element you want to insert, and then use `DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode` to select the position you want to insert.

For testing,you can refer to the following code:

Custom middleware:

```
//Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
public class ResponseMeasurementMiddleware
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ResponseMeasurementMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBody = context.Response.Body;
            var newBody = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = newBody;

            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            long responseTime = 0;
            watch.Start();
            await _next(context);
           // read the new body
            responseTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            newBody.Position = 0;
            var newContent = await new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEndAsync();
            // calculate the updated html
            var updatedHtml = CreateDataNode(newContent, responseTime);
            // set the body = updated html
            var updatedStream = GenerateStreamFromString(updatedHtml);
            await updatedStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
            context.Response.Body = originalBody;

        }
        public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
        private string CreateDataNode(string originalHtml, long responseTime)
        {
           var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(originalHtml);
            HtmlNode testNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode($"<div class=\"container\">Processing time: {responseTime.ToString()} ms.</div>");
            var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//body/div");
            if (htmlBody != null)
            {
                htmlBody.InsertBefore(testNode, htmlBody.FirstChild);
            }

            string rawHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; //using this results in a page that displays my inserted HTML correctly, but duplicates the original page content.
                                                             //rawHtml = "some text"; uncommenting this results in a page with the correct format: this text, followed by the original contents of the page

            return rawHtml;
        }
}
```

`htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//body/div")` and `htmlBody.InsertBefore(testNode, htmlBody.FirstChild)` can customize where you want to insert.

And use custom middleware:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ResponseMeasurementMiddleware>();
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: That works, but am afraid it is pretty heavy as we have to convert `Response.Body` to `MemoryStream` and back. Additionally intermediate string has to be parsed to `HtmlDocument` what is also resource intense. No simpler option?